# remove trailing dashes in foldtext

Tags: folding

When I set `foldtext` to a simple value like `getline(v:foldstart)`, vim should show the current line, as opposed to the usual `+` and appropriate number of hyphens `-` for the foldlevel. However, vim fills the remaining space till the far side of the window width with dashes, which I don't want. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Hey myc3lium, I feel like I've seen posts from you before, maybe on [so]? Maybe not... I can't seem to find anything. Anyways, welcome to [vi.se]! Great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to `:h 'fillchars'` option. You need

```
set fcs=fold:\ ,vert:\|
```

Comment: Oh hey matt. You seem to be the first one to reply whenever I (rarely) ask questions. Thanks for the solution